# Node Send Files as URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have an image file in the server side, and would like to send this image to the client side to display it in the web. It seems like `URL.createObjectURL` can only be used in a DOM, it sounds impossible to convert the image file to URL in expressJS, or is there any other way to return the image as URL from server side?

I am now trying to send the image buffer and try to use `URL.createObjectURL` on the client side. It seems like `res` containing a bunch of weird character string, and I tried to create a Blob, but the image does not render on the web at all.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:9000/foo`)
   .then((res) => res.text())
   .then((res) => {
      var test = new Blob([res], { type: "image/jpeg" });
      props.setImageSrc((prev) => [
         ...prev,
         URL.createObjectURL(test),
       ]);
});
```

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  var buffer = fs.readFileSync("/Users/foo/bar/image1.jpeg");
  var bufferBase64 = new Buffer.from(buffer);
  res.send(bufferBase64);
});
```

Below are part of the res I got on the client side
`%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������`

Comment: If you want to send base 64 from express, you should be doing `res.send(bufferBase64.toString("base64"));`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to convert the base64 buffer string to blob

```
const b64toblob = (string, fileType) => {
   const byteCharacters = atob(string);
   const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
   for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
     byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
   return new Blob([byteArray], { type: `image/${fileType}` });
};
```

Receive base64 buffer string from server

```
fetch(`http://localhost:9000/foo`)
   .then((res) => res.text())
   .then((res) => {
      const blob = b64toblob(buffer, "jpeg");
      props.setImageSrc((prev) => [
         ...prev,
         URL.createObjectURL(blob),
       ]);
});
```

In server, read the file and convert to base64 buffer

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  var buffer = fs.readFileSync("/Users/foo/bar/image1.jpeg");
  var bufferBase64 = new Buffer.from(buffer);
  res.send(bufferBase64.toString("base64"));
});
```